# Problem with font OT1-Greek letters

Tags: greek, font-encodings

I am having this problem. I got this sample by net:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\input{epsf.tex}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{
   \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1        % Name
   \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{
   \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1} % Slogan (optional)
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}


\begin{document}
\MyName{Constantinou Philippos}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that in commands `\MyName` and `\MySlogan` I want to use Greek characters but I know I cannot because I use font `OT1` which doesn't support Greek letters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've already told you that you can't use `phv` for getting Greek letters.

Comment: yes I know you did, but I cannot find any solution for that.

Comment: Use a sans serif font that supports Greek.

Answer (score 1):

A sans serif font supporting Greek is OpenSans:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{opensans}

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{{\Huge\sffamily#1\par}}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{{\large\sffamily\textit{#1}\par}}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\MyName{Κοσταντινου Φιλιππος}

\MySlogan{βιογραφικό σημείωμα}
\end{document}
```

[image]